# How get all rows of a specific pattern from sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

In Table some data are in some pattern like frequency,frequency[1],frequency[2]...

How get all rows of this pattern from table, if give frequency in where clause?

I am try with **'GLOB'** keyword, but it not return any more data.

**Query:**

```
 select * from tblfrequencyCustom where frequency  GLOB  'Ff' OR  'Ff[*]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not working because your condition is same that `(frequency GLOB 'Ff') OR  ('Ff[*]')`. `frequency  GLOB  'Ff'` has no wildcards, so is same as `frequency='Ff'`, which doesn't match your data. `'Ff[*]'` casts to integer `0`, which is always false.

So, you may use common SQL operator `LIKE` (case insensitive):

```
SELECT * FROM tblfrequencyCustom WHERE frequency='frequency' OR frequency LIKE 'frequency[%]';
```

Using less common operator `GLOB`, you must escape `[`and `]`:

```
SELECT * FROM tblfrequencyCustom WHERE frequency='frequency' OR frequency GLOB 'frequency[[]*[]]';
```

Comment: using like keyword it work perfect but using GLOB it not give any result.

Comment: Corrected! Using `GLOB`, `*` should be used instead of `%`. Maybe you can optimize your query using just `SELECT * FROM tblfrequencyCustom WHERE frequency GLOB 'frequency*';`